# Columns for SQL Reports are blank

Tags: reporting-services

My setup is Windows France OS, SQL 2012 France. 
The underlying stored procedure is returning correct results like date is shown as "dèc 11" but the same value doesn't appear in the corresponding date column in report. 
However, if I run the same report for English Windows and SQL 2012 English, it works fine. Also, If I hard code the date column returned by the stored procedure to "Dec 11", the report in French setup start showing the entries in date column.

Can you suggest what could be possible reasons for getting empty column reports in French environment?

Comment: @imdave Can you suggest what could be possible reasons for getting empty column reports in French environment?

Comment: What's your expression for that column? Does it have a format applied? If it does, remove the format and see what values come through.